# Read back chart details from highchart in json

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts

I need to read back the chart details like styles, type, and all the attributes which are used to display any chart by Highchart, i.e. similar to chart.getSVG(). I need something like chart.getJSON() to save the entire JSON template with user chosen colors, fonts, series location etc in the DB, except the "data".

When we do the automatic distribution of the above mentioned chart using HighChart server, we need to read the above template with all the user specific attributes, but insert new data values for X and Y which we have, i.e only values will be new here, not the style. What is the best way to do it?, i.e. read the user template on the chart, but generate pdf with the new values. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all non-default options set for chart from:

```
var userOptions = $("#container").highcharts().userOptions
```

So options used when creating chart are stored there. Now you can use that object (without `userOptions.series` array of course) to store in your DB.

To remove `series` array use this snippet:

```
delete userOptions.series
```

And now you can create object using:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(userOptions);
```

And send `myJSON` to you DB and store it.

Comment: Thx Pawel, I've additional qn to this..if I need to store more than 1 chart in a single JSON string, is that possible? Chart like jsfiddle.net/tg8f9fgo/5 or **/4/. If I am able to store all those 3 charts in one JSON string and able to generate the corresponding pdf, that would be great. Otherwise, I can store those individual JSON strings, read them, insert the corresponding data, create an image with the desired size and add them to one pdf. But,I just want to know whether we can create one JSON for all those charts & create pdf in one shot(similar to 1 SVG for multiple charts).

Comment: Sure, you can store all three charts in one JSON, however, to create multiple charts in one pdf you need to create three charts anyway.